# Scrollview only showing last dynamically added subview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I am trying to add a view from my storyboard to a UIScrollView. I need to add the view an X amount of times and I do this with a for loop

```
sectionViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SectionViewController") as! SectionViewController

...

for index in 0..<numberOfSections {
            let subViewFrame = CGRectMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index), -64, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)

            let subView = sectionViewController.view
            subView!.frame = subViewFrame
            subView.tag = index

            self.scrollView .addSubview(subView!)
        }
```

The ScrollView is created programmatically like this

```
self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)

self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
self.scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = false

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(numberOfSections), 0)
self.scrollView.scrollsToTop = false

scrollViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 100, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)

self.scrollView.frame = scrollViewFrame

self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)
```

So I add the subViews after this. The problem is that only the last subview is showing. So when numberOfSections = 10, only the 10th subview is showing. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning same view as subview  for all index(let subView = sectionViewController.view), for each index create different instance of SectionViewController view

Comment: I tried that and now I'm not seeing any subview at all. What you're saying makes a lot of sense so it must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

after @Annie_Dev 's suggestion try to assign different color for even and add subviews to check if subviews are added or not.

Comment: Did that now and all the subviews get a different background color, but only the last one shows the subview from the storyboard. No clue what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of digging around and trying a bunch of things, I finally found the problem. I had a lot of conflicting constraints in my subview. Once I had fixed those, everything showed up like it should.